# How to connect Heroku Discord Bot to CockroachDB?

Tags: heroku, cockroachdb

I currently have a discord bot built with Nextcord.py with a working database on CockroachDB.
I managed to host and deploy the bot on Heroku and commands work, but I can't seem to get the database to work.

The error line in the Heroku log is
`2023-06-14T10:29:55.300444+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch`

When I try the Worker instead of Web, I get this error when I try a command.

```
2023-06-14T10:46:44.323804+00:00 app[worker.1]: psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "enter server here" (IP), port 32481 failed: Connection timed out
2023-06-14T10:46:44.323805+00:00 app[worker.1]:     Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
2023-06-14T10:46:44.323806+00:00 app[worker.1]: connection to server at "enter server here" (IP), port 32481 failed: Connection timed out
2023-06-14T10:46:44.323806+00:00 app[worker.1]:     Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
2023-06-14T10:46:44.323806+00:00 app[worker.1]: connection to server at ""enter server here" (IP), port 32481 failed: Connection timed out
2023-06-14T10:46:44.323807+00:00 app[worker.1]:     Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

I connect to CockroachDB manually using Psycopg2 using the following code:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(
        host = os.getenv('HOST'),
        port = os.getenv('PORT'),
        database = os.getenv('DATABASE'),
        user = os.getenv('USER'),
        password = os.getenv('PASSWORD'),
        sslmode = os.getenv('SSLMODE')
        )
```

where the the enviorment variables are:

```
HOST=calmer-herring-5909.7tc.cockroachlabs.cloud
PORT=*port*
DATABASE=*database*
USER=*user*
PASSWORD=*password*
SSLMODE=verify-full
```

Is this a Heroku related problem? I can't seem to find out what's not working here.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us your DATABASE_URL or connection string? Remember to replace the password with something fake.

Comment: @AydrianHoward I've added the information, hope it is valid.

Comment: Are you sure the port you have specified is correct? I see the error message is referencing 32481. I think the Cockroach Cloud port is usually 26257.

Comment: @AydrianHoward I'm not really sure why the 32481 port is showing up.. The port in the config vars and in the .env file is 26257

Comment: Have you added your heroku app to the IP allowlist in Cockroach Cloud? https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/cockroachcloud/network-authorization.html

Comment: @AydrianHoward Unfortunately I don't think Heroku shares the IP to my application so I don't think there's a way to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found the solution.
I changed the Heroku dyno to Worker instead of Web, and in the connection string, the SSLMODE should be equal to "require", since it is impossible to install the CA certificate that CockroachDB requires make a connection to the database.
If you use any other SSLMODE than "required" (either verify-full or disable), it won't work.
Hope that helps

Comment: If you want to use the CA cert you can copy the contents of it into an environment variable and use it with pycopg2 that way. But glad to hear you figured it out.

Comment: @AydrianHoward Great insight, thank you! I'll try it if another problem with the connection pops up.